# How to access an image inside a DLL from inside the DLL?

Tags: delphi, dll, datamodule, timagelist, delphi-10.4-sydney

In Delphi 10.4, in a COM Server DLL ShellExtension project, I have added a `DataModule` to the project and placed a `TImageList` on the DataModule. The ImageList contains several images added at design-time. Now, from the main unit of the `DLL` project, I try to access an image in the ImageList:

```
procedure TMyShellExtension2.MyGetBitmap(ABitmap: Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap);
begin
  ABitmap.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
  ABitmap.Width := 128;
  ABitmap.Height := 128;
  DataModule.DataModule3.ilUrlPics.GetBitmap(0, ABitmap);
  CodeSite.Send('test');    
end;
```

The `GetBitmap` line seems to cause an error, as the following `CodeSite.Send` line is not being executed and the image is not assigned.

Obviously, my way of accessing the image from a `TImageList` on a `DataModule` inside a `DLL` is not correct.

On the other hand, when assigning a "self-made" BitMap, it **does work**:

```
ABitmap.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
ABitmap.Width := 128;
ABitmap.Height := 128;
ABitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlue;
ABitmap.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, 127, 127));
```

Is there another working way of accessing an image inside a `DLL`? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try catching exceptions (in case one is thrown by `GetBitmap`)?

Comment: When trying to include `GetBitmap` inside `try except` with a `ShowMessage` statement, at runtime (windows File Explorer in this case is the host) I get an `Access Violation`.

Comment: You just need to debug it. Find out which memory access leads to the AV. You can do that using code site.

Comment: Exactly. After having replaced `ShowMessage` by `CodeSite.Send` I got this exception: "...: Exception = EAccessViolation error raised, with message : Access Violation..."

Comment: I'll try this BEFORE `GetBitmap`: `CodeSite.Send('MyGetBitmap: IL Assigned?', Assigned(DataModule.DataModule3.ilUrlPics));`

Comment: `CodeSite` tells me that `DataModule.DataModule3` does not exist (Assigned = False)!!! So why a `DataModule` created at design-time does not exist at run-time in a `DLL`?

Comment: @user1580348: Perhaps its constructor raises an exception?

Comment: @user1580348 because a DLL project doesn't have startup code in its EntryPoint to create design-time objects at runtime, like a Form GUI project does. So you will have to explicitly create the `TDataModule` object yourself.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I don't think so. Maybe `DataModule` isn't supposed to be used in a DLL. But meanwhile, I have solved the problem by storing the Bitmaps with `Project → Resources and Images` and loading the Bitmap at run-time with `ABitmap.LoadFromResourceName`. This works!

Comment: That's might actually be a better approach; otherwise, probably Remy's remark is spot on.

Comment: @RemyLebeau In the `OnCreate` event-handler of the `DataModule` unit?

Comment: @user1580348 no, I mean in the DLL's **entry point** (the `begin..end.` block of the project's main source file, or in a `DllProc` callback). And besides, *units* don't have events, *classes* do. However, in a DLL, using resources is a better solution than using a `TImageList` on a `TDataModule`.

Comment: I want to say THANK YOU to ALL commentators who contributed their valuable knowledge to the community! This is a great community!

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Regarding my answer for the question "From the IDE's Structure Panel, how to copy a TCard to the clipboard?" (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63336038/from-the-ides-structure-panel-how-to-copy-a-tcard-to-the-clipboard/63338826), where you have edited my answer: Why is my answer no more accepted since you edited it? What did you edit in that answer?

Comment: @user1580348: You can always see the difference an edit made by clicking the ["edited N hours ago" text](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63338826/revisions). In this case, you can see my edit comment "for users of screen readers, search engines, etc." and the actual edit: "enter image description here" was replaced by "MainForm". Every time you include an image on a web page, you should give it an alternative text for visually impaired people who use screen readers. And also to aid Google and other computer programs. If you put a picture of a black carrot on the web and someone searches...

Comment: ...on Google for "black carrot", they won't find it without the alt text. So IMHO you should always provide a nice alt text. I often include alt texts several sentences long describing screenshots and other more complex images. So that's the edit I made. I am really surprised the edit affected the "accepted" status of the answer. I had no idea it would. Can you not tick it again?

Comment: I gave you a +1 as "compensation". :)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Thank you for your edit of my answer and for the explanation of the Alt text. I will use it in the future. And also thank you for your help in general! I have learned a lot from you. And you are a very friendly and constructive person!

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Something must have gone wrong, there is no image description there: `[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqlfe.png`

Comment: @user1580348: Thank you for your kind words. Regarding the alt text: The alt text is stored at the point of reference (in the main part of the text): `[![MainForm][1]][1]`. The generated HTML of the page reveals that it is present: `<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqlfe.png" alt="MainForm">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As several commentators in this question have pointed out and as I have experienced myself, using resources as image-source in DLLs is a better methodology than "using a `TImageList` on a `TDataModule`" which would have to be explicitly instantiated in the DLL's entry point (as @RemyLebeau has pointed out).

So in this specific case I:

• Store the needed images as Bitmaps in `Project → Resources and Images`.

• Make sure to load the created resource e.g. with `{$R MyShellExtensionDLL.res}`.

• Load the Bitmaps at run-time with e.g.:

```
procedure MyGetBitmap(ABitmap: Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap);  
begin  
  ABitmap.PixelFormat := pf24bit;  
  ABitmap.Width := 128;  
  ABitmap.Height := 128;  
  ABitmap.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance,'BITMAP1');  
end;
```