# From the IDE's Structure Panel, how to copy a TCard to the clipboard?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-10.4-sydney

In the Delphi 10.4 IDE Form Designer's `STRUCTURE PANEL`, I select a `TCard` container control (containing several controls) and try to copy it to the clipboard with `CTRL+C`. It does not work. Even in the EDIT sub-context menu, the Copy item is disabled:

[image]

Restarted the IDE. Tried again and again for hours.

Is there a trick to do this? Is this a bug in the IDE?

Comment: Must be something volatile. I can copy a TCard and paste it into the TCardPanel from the Structure View context menu here. Then later the Copy command is disabled. After opening the context menu in the Form Designer, the Structure View context menu is working again.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a bug in the IDE that interrupts the synchronization between `Structure Panel` and `Form Designer` for specific object types like `TCard` or `TTabSheet` and similar containers.

This is a workaround for this bug:

1. First select the `TCard` in the Structure Panel
2. Then click on the Form Designer's TAB [image: MainForm] to focus the `TCard` in the Form Designer
3. Then press `CTRL+C` to copy the `TCard` together with all its sub-controls to the clipboard - this works!